# how to handle special characters ( ഀ ) in file

Tags: unix, bpel

I have a file which looks like this when I open it Notepad ++

```
         A|B|C|D|E਍ഀ
        31|HB|39|Ph|49਍ഀ
        32|FB|38|Ph|59਍ഀ
```

When I try to open it from WinScp , it looks like as below

```
        ÿþA|B|C|D|E

         31|HB|39|Ph|49

         32|FB|38|Ph|59
```

I want to read this file in BPEL File Adapter. But I am unable to read it as the {eol} is not proper.Moreover I have tried ਍ഀ as end of line but no luck.

PFA

<  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc8B8.png >

Thanks In Advance,

Abhishek

Comment: You have to understand what exactly the file contains. I'd suggest you to run - on Unix - the following command: `od -c your_file` to get an octal dump.

Comment: @mauro .. Hi.. I have checked with that command and understood the issue. The issue lies in converting LF to CRLF in unix. could you please help me with the required command .Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @BapuAbhi: I refuse to believe that you didn't actually find anything about LF<=>CRLF conversion searching on Google.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Tried a lot a links .. but not successful yet.. till I am working on it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the output of `od -c`? I doubt both CR and LF would cause that box you see in output. Anyhow... you can use the following sed command to get rid of the extra CR at the end of each line: `sed 's/\x0D$//' old_file > new_file`

Comment: Hi @mauro  ..Sorry for the delya..please find the output of od -c   0000000 377 376   A  \0   |  \0   B  \0   |  \0   C  \0   |  \0   D  \0
0000020   |  \0   E  \0  \r  \n  \0  \r  \n  \0   3  \0   1  \0   |  \0
0000040   H  \0   B  \0   |  \0   3  \0   9  \0   |  \0   P  \0   h  \0
0000060   |  \0   4  \0   9  \0  \r  \n  \0  \r  \n  \0   3  \0   2  \0
0000100   |  \0   F  \0   B  \0   |  \0   3  \0   8  \0   |  \0   P  \0
0000120   h  \0   |  \0   5  \0   9  \0  \r  \n  \0  \r  \n  \0
0000136

Comment: @BapuAbhiAs I suspected your input file is... a little bit messy... Comment is too short. Will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you ran od -c on this file (see comments here above) you found:

```
0000000 377 376 A \0 | \0 B \0 | \0 C \0 | \0 D \0 
0000020 | \0 E \0 \r \n \0 \r \n \0 3 \0 1 \0 | \0 
0000040 H \0 B \0 | \0 3 \0 9 \0 | \0 P \0 h \0 
0000060 | \0 4 \0 9 \0 \r \n \0 \r \n \0 3 \0 2 \0 
0000100 | \0 F \0 B \0 | \0 3 \0 8 \0 | \0 P \0 
0000120 h \0 | \0 5 \0 9 \0 \r \n \0 \r \n \0 
0000136
```

Let's start from the beginning.

Did you notice the first two bytes? Octal 377 and 376. Alias 0xFF 0xFE hex. This is the so-called Byte Order Mark (BOM). It's used to "deliver" information to the application that will have to read the file (encoding and endianness).

Now, if BOM is 0xFF 0xFE it means the the file contains Unicode Characters encoded UTF-16. To be precise it's a Little Endian UTF-16 encoded file (UTF-16LE).

As your file is encoded UTF-16LE... every character requires **two bytes**:

- the first character (Latin Capital letter A) is represented by "A \0"
- the second character is "| \0"
- the third character is "B \0"
- and so on...

So far... so good. The problem is "\r \n". This sequence would be the usual CR LF **if the file was encoded UTF-8** but the BOM says the file is encoded UTF-16LE so...

- Carriage Return should be represented by 0x0D 0x00 (\r \0 in od -c)
- New Line by 0x0A 0x00 (\n \0 in od -c)

The fact that you have "\r \n" instead of "\r \0 \n \0" confuses the application that doesn't know how to "interpret" these bytes using UTF-16LE encoding. The sequence "\r \n" in UTF-16LE is invalid and the application uses two "boxes" to represent these invalid bytes.

To keep it short: your file is badly encoded (half UTF-16LE and half UTF-8). I guess someone did use notepad or stuff like that to alter its content.

You can **try** using iconv and/or sed to fix it.

Comment: @ Mauro  ...Thanks for your reply. But I am getting the file in pgp encrypted format. I have decrypted the file and shared the content of that file. I know the issue is in LF. It should have been CRLF so that my BPEL file adapter can read and process...                                                                           When I copied the content manually,placed in Notepad ++ , the CRLF is getting displayed in the file.

Comment: I have used the following command to remove \0 and  |\0 
  CMD ->  u2dos() (set -f; IFS='
'; printf '%s\r\n' $(cat "$1"))

u2dos oldfile.txt > newfile.txt                                                                          But as I told earlier I was able to add CRLF in DOS by the following cmd and did not get any appropriate command in unix                                      FIND "" /V <oldfile.txt >newfile.txt .                            Could you please let me know the exact command to add CRLF                                          sed 's/\x0D$//' old_file > new_file did not work

Comment: @BapuAbhi. Now I'm confused... The actual content of your file is clear and explains why you get those two "boxes" when you try to visualise it. That said, could you please explain us how do you want to change this file and why? What's your scope by removing bytes encoded as '\0'? Why do you want to add CRLF? CRLF (unfortunately) are already there and they make this file not-compatible with the BOM reported in the file itself.