# Extra characters added when using python 3 write function

Tags: python-3.x, io

I'm doing an exercise from Learn Python3 The Hard Way. This is the following example:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

indata = open(from_file).read()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

out_file.close()
```

If I run the script with these arguments:

`python ex17.py test.txt new_file.txt`

then I get the following after I use `cat` to view the file:

```
This is a test file.਍ഀ
```

What are these characters at the end? Opening the file is notepad has two different sized boxes. Would this be counted as a newline or something else? If I write a file in Python 3 how can I keep these added characters from appearing?

Comment: Does it exist in `cat test.txt`? An easy way to check would be `ord(indata[-1])`.

Comment: What does `file test.txt` report? You may also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413073/